# Given a field extension $L : K : F$, if $L:F$ and $K:F$ are finitely generated then so is $L:K$.

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, extension-field

I'm trying to find a source for the proposition from the title: if $L : K : F$ is a tower of field extensions, and furthermore both $L$ and $K$ are finitely generated over $F$, then $L$ is finitely generated over $K$.

This statement does not seem to be in Dummit and Foote, and I have had no luck finding a proof online. Does anybody have a reference, source, or proof for it?

Comment: It does, but I need to use this proposition in a case where $L$ has transcedental elements over $F$.

Comment: @arctictern that's not quite the proposition I have: you're proving that if $L:K$ and $K:F$ are finitely generated, then so is $L:F$. I need that if $L:F$ and $K:F$ are finitely generated, then so is $L:K$.

Comment: @OpenBall no; consider $\mathbb Q(\pi) : \mathbb Q$. Since $\pi$ is transcedental over $\mathbb Q$, then the degree of this extension is infinite (right?), yet this extension is certainly finitely generated.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Anyway OP, ignoring $K/F$ being finitely generated, if $L/K/F$ is a tower and $L=F(\ell_1,\cdots,\ell_r)$ then surely $L=K(\ell_1,\cdots,\ell_r)$ too?

Comment: @arctictern yeah, I just realized. I was thinking way too hard about this question, and it's actually really easy, as you noted :)

Comment: @OpenBall the definition of $L$ being finitely generated over $F$ is just that $L$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and some finite number of elements $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_s \in L$. Here we have $L = \mathbb Q(\pi)$ and $F = \mathbb Q$, and also $\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_s\} = \{\pi\}$. So really we have $\{\pi\}$ is the generating set. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out a proof. It turns out it's way simpler that I thought it would be, and I didn't think about it enough before posting the question.

If $L : F$ is finitely generated, then by definition that means that there are some $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_s \in L$ such that $L$ is the smallest field (by inclusion) containing $F$ all the $\alpha_i$. Now consider some intermediate field $K$ (so $L : K : F$ is a tower of extensions). Certainly $L$ contains $K$, and $L$ contains all the $\alpha_i$, and if $L$ was not the smallest field containing $K$ and the $\alpha_i$, then it would also not be the smallest field containing $F$ and the $\alpha_i$, since $F \leq K$, which is absurd since $L$ is finitely generated over $F$. Therefore $L$ is finitely generated over $K$.